Query Parameters Not Populating Correctly in WSO2 API
I'm working with an Aggregate API configuration. I have defined query parameters oc and cid in my API definition, but when I make requests, these parameters seem to be empty or not populated correctly. This issue leads to errors like INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR and NumberFormatException.
Here is my API configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/aggregate" name="CombinedAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/getData">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.oc')" name="oc" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.cid')" name="cid" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
            <clone>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/usersDS/getUsers">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                 
                        <property expression="get-property('response')" name="userResponse" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/officesDS/getOffice?OfficeCode={oc}">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log level="full" separator=",">
                            <property expression="get-property('response')" name="Office Service Response"/>
                        </log>
                        <property expression="get-property('response')" name="officeResponse" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/productsDS/getProduct?category_id={cid}">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log level="full" separator=",">
                            <property expression="get-property('response')" name="Product Service Response"/>
                        </log>
                        <property expression="get-property('response')" name="productResponse" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
            <aggregate>
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="3"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" expression="json-eval($)">
                    <log level="full" separator=",">
                        <property expression="json-eval($)" name="Aggregated Response"/>
                    </log>
                    <property expression="json-eval($)" name="aggregatedResponse" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <log level="full" separator=",">
                        <property expression="get-property('aggregatedResponse')" name="Final Aggregated Response"/>
                    </log>
                    <respond/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

and the error i am encountering:
<DataServiceFault>
            <current_params>{category_id=}</current_params>
            <source_data_service>
                <data_service_name>productsDS</data_service_name>
                <description>Service to expose product data</description>
                <location>C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1718856451086TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\productsDS_1.0.0\productsDS-1.0.0.dbs</location>
                <default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice</default_namespace>
            </source_data_service>
            <ds_code>INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR</ds_code>
            <nested_exception>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""</nested_exception>
            <current_request_name>_getgetproduct</current_request_name>
        </DataServiceFault>

For some reason the parameters are not being populated correctly.

Your property names have to follow uri.var.* format for this to work. So change it as follows:
<property expression="get-property('query.param.oc')" name="uri.var.oc" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
.
.
.

.
.
<http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8290/services/officesDS/getOffice?OfficeCode={uri.var.oc}">
    <suspendOnFailure>
        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
    </suspendOnFailure>
    <markForSuspension>
        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
    </markForSuspension>
</http>
.
.

